# Eclipse : Importing web application

Tags: eclipse, web

Hi,

I have to import some web application into Eclipse IDE.I know the way to import :

File->import->web->War file. But in my Eclipse IDE, I am unable to find web.I clicked on File->import, then a window was opened:

It contailns only :

- General & CVS & Install & Maven&Run & Debug&Tasks & Team & XML options only.There is now such option "Web". Where I can find it?..Please help me....

Comment: You eclipse version does not support web project it seems.

Comment: Which Eclipse package (Java EE?) and version (3.7?) are using?

Comment: I'm in JavaEE perspective ,Version: Indigo Service Release 2,
Build id: 20120216-1857

Comment: @RamaRaoM Well? Does my answer helped your issue?

Comment: @AbdulAziz Not actually, U meant to say I need to again download Eclipse for J2EE development and install...Actually in my IDE, I was succeed to import web application, that time I found  Web option,but I cant find now,Might I have changed some settings or something else...Thats what I m asking....

Comment: @RamaRaoM Ok first thing first. At menu bar , go to Help-->About eclipse, a window will open that list all the plugin you have in your eclipse version in **icon** form. List it here for me, so I will tell you what is missing.

Comment: @RamaRaoM Add comments under my answer to help you in better way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got what your eclipse is missing. Its "Web Tool platform for eclipse". Here is the link for it:
[Web tool eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/).

But remember that importing existing projects into Eclipse works only for projects that were created in Eclipse. Install it and the web perspective will appear in eclipse.

And you're definitely not dealing with an Archive File here.

Import from the File System just copies the resources but does not actually create an Eclipse project for you.

So I recommend you to build / create new web dynamic project, configuring all the required facets, and then just copy all the contents of your existing application to the WebContent of the project. But as I said first install the web tool plugin to eclipse. If you need more help let me know.

**EDIT :** Right click on your project and go to properties and then at the left side select "Project Facets" (If it asks for converting your project to facets, then do it, it helps a lot) then select your Facets.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help....I'm sorry, I could not find such option in my properties panel... There is no such option "Project Facets"..there is only one option starts with "Project" is "Project References".... Looking forward for your reply

Comment: The list of plugins in my Eclipse versiosn are:1.Eclipse Packaging Project
2.Eclipse Web Tools platform
3.Eclipse MyLyn
4.Eclipse Org
5.Eclipse Org - m2e